# Where can I follow the latest intellectual and academic developments in Kant research?

Tags: reference-request, kant

By this, I mean specifically the academic research, and since I am primarily interested in Kant, so on Kant too.

Answer (score 4):

Not that I'm an expert on this, but here's a couple suggestions:

1. Wikipedia has an article with a list of philosophy journals. While I'm sure many journals include articles about Kant, there is a [journal dedicated to talking about Kant](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayJournal?jid=KRV). These obviously can be very expensive, so if you have access to a college library, it is probably better to go through that then buying yourself.
2. Another approach is instead of trying to follow all of academic development in philosophy (or even within a specific topic), you can do the opposite: find a few people who write about topics you are interested in, and read their books, see if they have videos on YouTube, subscribe to their blog, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your top interest is Kant and you truly want to get involved in the academic literature, then the top journal is [*Kant Studien*](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/kant).

Also, you should look at the work of Henry Allison, Marcia Baron, Thomas Hill, Christine Korsgaard, Nora O'Neill, and Allen Wood. (I'm sure I'm missing some important people there, but this is a good place to start to learn about contemporary Kantianism).